Lagrange interpolation and orthogonal polynomials
Suppose that $\{p_i(x)\}_{i=0}^{n}$ are pairwise orthogonal polynomials on the interval $[a,b]$, It means,
$$
\int_{a}^{b} p_i(x)p_j(x)dx = 0\ , \;{i\neq j}
$$
wherein $p_i(x)$ for all $i$ is a polynomial of degree $i$.
I) Prove that for every polynomial $q_{2n-1}(x)$ of degree $2n-1$, we have:
$$
\int_{a}^{b} q_{2n-1}(x)dx = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i q_{2n-1}(x_i),
$$
wherein
$$
\lambda_i = \int_{a}^{b} L_i(x)dx,
$$
$$
L_i(x) = \frac{p_n(x)}{p'_n(x_i)(x-x_i)},
$$
and  $x_i$  for $1\leq i \leq n$ are roots of $p_n(x)$. ($x_i$'s are distinct.)
II) Prove that:
$$
\int_{a}^{b} L_i(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b} L^2_i(x)dx
$$
wherein $L_i(x)$'s are basic Lagrange polynomials  based on $x_1,...,x_n$ be distinct roots of $p_n(x)$.
My attempt: because $p_0(x)$ is a constant, then $\int_{a}^{b} p_i(x)dx = 0$ for all $i \neq 0$, from here we can conclude that $\int_{a}^{b} p_n(x)x^k dx = 0$ ($0\leq k \lt n$) so $\int_{a}^{b} p_n(x)g_{n-1}(x)dx = 0$ for all polynomials of degree $n-1$ like $g_{n-1}$. By these statements I could prove part(I), but I do not know how to show part(II).
Thank you for your time.

Since $L_i$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$, $L_i^2$ is of degree $2n-2$, thus we can reuse (I),
$$\int_a^b L_i^2(x)dx = \sum \lambda_j L_i^2(x_j) = \lambda_i.$$
And by (I), $\lambda_i = \int_a^b L_i(x) dx$.

but part $I$ is correct for polynomials of degree $2n-1$, how do you justify this?

degree $2n-2$ polynomial is also a (degenerated) degree $2n-1$ polynomial with leading coefficient zero. @schneiderlog
